# Unable to select table.. php & mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I created a table & when Submit button is hit after filling the form, those particulars should be inserted into the DB TABLE. But idk what's wrong with the code, it's echoing "Unable to select table".. My code is as follows:

```
<?php

if ( isset ( $_POST['submit'] ) ) 
{
mysql_connect("localhost","root","1234");
mysql_select_db("my_db")or die( "Unable to select database</span></p>");

$name1 = $_POST['name1'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$password = $_POST['password'];
$confirmpassword = $_POST['confirmpassword'];
$gender = $_POST['gender'];
$place = $_POST['place'];
$college = $_POST['college'];



$result=MYSQL_QUERY("INSERT INTO USERS3 (id,name1,email,password,confirmpassword,gender,college,place)".
"VALUES ('NULL', '$name1', '$email', '$password', '$confirmpassword', '$gender', '$place', '$college')")or die( "<p><span style=\"color: red;\">Unable to select table</span></p>");
mysql_close();

echo "<p><span style=\"color: red;\">Thank You;</span></p>"; 
}

else
{
// close php so we can put in our code
?>

<form id="form1" action="" method="post">
Name:
<input type="text" name="name1" /><br/>
E-mail:
<input type="text" name="email" /><br/>
Password:
<input type="password" name="password" /><br/>
Confirm Password:
<input type="password" name="confirmpassword" /><br/>
Gender:
<input type="radio" name="gender" />
Male
<input type="radio" name="gender" />
Female
<br/>
Location:
<input type="text" name="place" /><br/>
College:
<input type="text" name="college" /><br/>
<input id="submit1" class="submit" type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit"/><br/>
<input type="reset" value="reset" />
</form>

<?php
} //close the else statement
?>
```

Comment: A general recommendation: Use mysqli or PDO instead of the deprecated mysql extension!

Answer (score 0):

PHP doesn't recognise function with capital letters. Use small-case characters:

```
mysql_query( "INSERT INTO USERS3 ( id, name1, email, 
        `password`, confirmpassword, gender, college, place)
    VALUES ('NULL', '$name1', '$email', 
        '$password', '$confirmpassword', '$gender', '$place', 
        '$college')") or die( "<p><span style=\"color: red;\">Unable to select table</span></p>");
mysql_close();
```

Answer (score 0):

If 'id' is an autoincrement field, you shouldn't be passing any value for it - the database will deal with that.

Answer (score 0):

Everything looks fine.Only problem(s) could be:

The table name might be incorrect.Especially, i suspect your correct table name is `users3` instead of  `USERS3` .

The ideal way to check is:

Add following statement before **$result=**.....

```
echo "INSERT INTO USERS3 (id,name1,email,password,confirmpassword,gender,college,place)".
"VALUES ('NULL', '$name1', '$email', '$password', '$confirmpassword', '$gender', '$place', '$college')";
```

**Run/Load** the page.

Whatever is printed - **copy it**.

Go to **phpmyadmin** and select **SQL** Tab.Paste what you copied in previous step and run it.

phpmyadmin will display the exact error.